# MySql random category limited select

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to create a query that will select one item for first category, two items for second and 2 items for third category, for others just one item.

The problem is it has to be one query. I think this is possible but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT i.*
          FROM ITEM i
         WHERE i.categoryid = 1
         LIMIT 1),
       (SELECT i.*
          FROM ITEM i
         WHERE i.categoryid = 2
         LIMIT 2),
       (SELECT i.*
          FROM ITEM i
         WHERE i.categoryid = 3
         LIMIT 2)
```

...will select one item for first category, two items for second and 2 items for third category.  I'd use `UNION ALL` over `UNION`, because it is faster due to it not removing duplicates.  Without knowing more about the data model (tables involved), it's difficult to say what would work best.

Comment: Ehm, this is a cross join, it will not return 5 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need the [SQL `UNION` operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp). As mentioned in the comments, though, we'd need to know what your table looks like to give much more help.